# May i know why it is not reading the declaration?

Tags: javascript

Below code execute only smith. Hello is not executing.
If i write document.write("Hello") its working. Why it is not happening with var. Explain this clearly.

```js
function x(a) {
    var s = "Hello";
    a(s);
    }

function y() {
    document.write("Smith");
    }

x(y);
```

Comment: What is the expected output/behavior?

Comment: You're only ever outputting one thing (count the number of `document.write` in your code), and that is "Smith"…

Comment: Because `y` doesn't have a parameter, and you're not passing that missing parameter to `document.write`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y` function does not accept or use a parameter, so giving it "hello" will not do anything.

You need to change `y` to something like

```
function y(extraText){
  document.write('Smith');
  document.write(extraText);
}
```

So you see, `y` now has a parameter called `extraText` and so when you call it with "hello" it will write both "Smith" and "hello".

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment...

> Because `y` doesn't have a parameter, and you're not passing that missing parameter to `document.write`

To fix your code, you need to add a parameter to `y` and then use that parameter...

```js
function x(a) {
  var s = "Hello";
  a(s);
}

function y(b) {
  document.write(b);
}

x(y);
```